# Lemma 13.3 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Is this reformulation correct?

Tags: general-topology, logic

Here is Lemma 13.3 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{B}^\prime$ be bases for the topologies $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{T}^\prime$, respectively, on $X$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (1) $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ is finer than $\mathscr{T}$.
>
> (2) For each $x \in X$ and each basis element $\mathcal{B} \in \mathscr{B}$ containing $x$, there is a basis element $\mathcal{B}^\prime \in \mathscr{B}^\prime$ such that $x \in \mathcal{B}^\prime \subset \mathcal{B}$.

I think I understand Munkres' proof.

Now my question is, can we formulate the above result as follows?

> Let $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{B}^\prime$ be bases for the topologies $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{T}^\prime$, respectively, on $X$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (1) $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ is finer than $\mathscr{T}$.
>
> (2) For each basis element $\mathcal{B} \in \mathscr{B}$  and each $x \in \mathcal{B}$, there is a basis element $\mathcal{B}^\prime \in \mathscr{B}^\prime$ such that $x \in \mathcal{B}^\prime \subset \mathcal{B}$.

I mean is the last statement equivalent to Lemma 13.3 in Munkres? If not, then is the last statement a correct (i.e. true) statement about topological spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read correctly it's about the order of quantifiers you're wondering about.

For each $x \in X$ and each basis element $\mathcal{B} \in \mathscr{B}$ containing $x$, there is a basis element $\mathcal{B}^\prime \in \mathscr{B}^\prime$ such that $x \in \mathcal{B}^\prime \subset \mathcal{B}$.

vs.

For each basis element $\mathcal{B} \in \mathscr{B}$  and each $x \in \mathcal{B}$, there is a basis element $\mathcal{B}^\prime \in \mathscr{B}^\prime$ such that $x \in \mathcal{B}^\prime \subset \mathcal{B}$.

Both are logically equivalent to

$$\forall x \in X \forall \mathcal{B} \in \mathscr{B}: ((x \in \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow (\exists \mathcal{B}' \in \mathscr{B}': (x \in \mathcal{B}') \land (\mathcal{B}' \subset \mathcal{B}))$$

So the order of universal quantifiers does not matter. You quantify over all pairs $(x,\mathcal{B})\subset X \times \mathscr{B}$ with $x \in \mathcal{B}$ essentially.